# Paginacion no respeta filtros en django

Tags: django

Hola buenas espero esten super,sucede que soy nuevo en django y estoy realizando una paginacion en un listview. Hasta ahi todo bien, le agregue un filtro de busqueda por fechas y filtra sin problema. Pero cuando uso el next de la paginacion habiendo echo el filtro, me muestra todos los registros. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Edgardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte debes de formular la pregunta correctamente y brindar un nivel de detalle adecuado. Te invito a leer el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: puedes compartir el tu view

Comment: pero tu tienes que realizar el filtro y luego a ese resultado lo paginas

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto un trozo de código para que lo modifiques según tu código.

### View

```
class ProductoFiltrar(FilterView):
    model = Producto
    filterset_class = ProductoFilter
    paginate_by = '50'
    is_paginated = True

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
     context = super(ProductoFiltrar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
     parametros = self.request.GET.copy()
     if parametros.get('page') != None:
        del parametros['page']
        context['parametros'] = parametros
     return context
```

### Template

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li>
            <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}">Anterior</a></span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
        <li class="">
            <span>Página {{ page_obj.number }} de {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</span>
        </li>
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li>
            <span><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}">Siguiente</a></span>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

De esta forma copiará los parametros de filtro y eliminará el parametro página para sobreescribirlo por la nueva página.

`FilterView` es una clase de una librería llamada `django-filter`, como no sé como tienes creada tu view te adjunto la librería. [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/)